# PostgreSQL: Crear Usuario (administrador) para una única base de datos

Tags: sql, postgresql, users-roles

Buen día, quisiera saber de que manera puedo crear un usuario (con todos los privilegios) pero que tenga acceso a una única base de datos:
Actualmente tengo 3 base de datos: base1, base2, db_test

¿Cómo podría hacer para crear un usuario y que este sólo pueda tener acceso total a la **db_test**?
He intentando con roles pero aún así cuando conecto por pgadmin (con el nuevo usuario) tengo acceso a todas las base de datos del servidor.

EL usuario no debería tener acceso de ningún tipo a la base1 y base2.

**Edit:**
Lo que intente fue crear el usuario y asignar los privilegios a la BD creada en el punto 2.

-- 1. Crear usuario/rol

**create user user_test with password 'user_test';**

-- 2. Crear BD

**create database db_test;**

-- 3. Permitir acceso de usuario user_test en la bd:

**grant all privileges on database db_test TO user_test;**

Necesito que cuando haga una conexion por medio de este usuario **user_test** él solo tenga acceso a la base de datos **db_test**, sin embargo cuando hago la conexión este usuario puede ver las demás base de datos también.

Comment: Hola! Bienvenidx a SOes. 
Las preguntas del tipo "Tengo que hacer esto" sin mostrar el código que has escrito no suelen ser bien recibidas, ya que la respuesta será siempre adivinando y no encaja en el formato del sitio.
Recomiendo que hagas el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender el sitio y de paso ganar tu primera medalla. 
También estaría bien que revisaras [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que recibas respuesta cuanto antes.

Comment: "He intentado" debe ir acompañado del cómo lo intentaste. Las consultas y el resultado. Que podamos ver y no nos toque adivinar. Recuerda que puedes [edit] tu pregunta cuantas veces sea necesario (incluso si termina cerrada) y añadir la info relevante a forma de [Ejemplo mínimo](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)
(en los comentarios no se ve bien el código y abajo sólo van nuestros intentos de respuesta).

Comment: El formato del sitio es de _preguntas y respuestas_. Si ya encontraste solución, ponlo como respuesta, y [acéptala](/help/accepted-answer). Además, como te han indicado, debes mostrar lo que habías intentado anteriormente. Lee [answer] y [ask], y haz (de nuevo) el [tour] para entender el funcionamiento del sitio.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solución:

-- 1. Revocar privilegios de todas las BD del rol/grupo publico

**revoke all privileges on database db_basex from public;**

De esta forma se limita el acceso a cualquier usuario que no sea "postgres"

-- 2. Crear usuario/rol [se pueden agregar roles segun se considere necesario]

**create user user_test with password 'user_test';**

--3. Crear BD [solo debera acceder el usuario user_test]

**create database db_test;**

-- 4. Retirar privilios a usuarios publicos de la BD creada

**revoke all privileges on database db_test from public;**

-- 5. Permitir acceso de usuario user_test en la bd:

**grant all privileges on database db_test TO user_test;**

Los únicos que podran acceder a esta bd son usuario: postgres y user_test